# Sorting and comparing an array based off of another array?

Tags: php

I have what seems to be a pretty simple problem, but having difficulties arriving at the solution in an elegant way.

I have a simple administration system for a client whereby they can log in order their videos on their website. It uses jQuery UI’s draggable component, and then the result is saved as a JSON file and parsed by the front-end. My problem now though is, the JSON file may become out of date if the client uploads any videos to their Vimeo account

So now I’m fetching videos from their Vimeo account but left with the problem of, how do I order videos based on the previously-saved order, but appending any newly-uploaded videos to the end of the list for the client to be able to order?

Answers in PHP please!

Comment: We demand you to show us some code :D

Comment: new videos: http://php.net/array_diff - sorting an array based on another: http://php.net/array_multisort - however if you only need to add the new to the list and the old list is already sorted, then there is not much to sort.

Comment: I’m just having difficulty with the normal method of going about this, as the arrays are mutlidimensional, so I don’t have the ID as the key to sort on.